# DIV container not taking height

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following CSS which makes images break row after it reaches the end of the DIV but the DIV container behind it is not taking height according to the images. The height should expand along with the images. Here is the screenshot http://prnt.sc/e3fqvr.

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    width: 163px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.proof-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.container-inside {
    border: 1px solid #1df2f2;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;   
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inside">
      <div class="container-title">Images</div>
      <br>
      <div class="proof-container">
        <?php while($faf = $prooq->fetch()){ extract($faf); ?>
        <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="https://wallpaperstock.net/wallpapers/thumbs1/45957hd.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
            <span><?php echo date('jS M, Y (h:i a)', strtotime($pr_uptime)); ?></span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
          <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please help me devs.

Comment: Can you show the css of images, please?

Comment: Why `.proof-container` is absolute? It is absolute so height is not taking image space and you haven't written any js to get image height and container. You should paste some fiddle demo.

Comment: its one huge different stylesheet @KevinJimenez

Comment: @locateganesh even if it is not absolute the height is not taking image space, also if not made absolute the last image in the row is also coming down to the other row...

Comment: I think you give to the image the property float, this make the container  not taking the proper height. Can you see that?

Comment: @locateganesh thanks you I figured it out.. I set .proof-container to relative and .container-inside to absolute. Now the DIV is taking height. But the last image of the row came down adding to the 2nd row. Any fix for it?

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove css property

```
 position:absolute from proof-container
```

And add

```
overflow:hidden to .container-inside div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `.container-inside` to `float:left`. If you don't want float. Then simply give `clearfix` class to `.container-inside` and add clearfix property.

**[float Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rv6ko834/)**

**[clearfix fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rv6ko834/2/)**

and remove absolute from `.proof-container` if not required.

And make `model` `display:none` because you want to show model on click of the images. Make model `position:absolute` and adjust as you want.

**[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv6ko834/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto` to `.container-inside` and remove `position: absolute` from `.proof-container`

```css
.image-container {
  width: 163px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-right: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.proof-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.container-inside {
  border: 1px solid #1df2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inside">
    <div class="container-title">Images</div>
    <br>
    <div class="proof-container">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="https://wallpaperstock.net/wallpapers/thumbs1/45957hd.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
        <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> 
        <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow: auto to `.container-inside` and remove position: absolute from `.proof-container` add the style to your modal as below.

```css
.image-container {
    width: 163px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 0px 65px 0px;
    float:left;
}

.proof-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
}

   .container-inside {
    border: 1px solid #1df2f2;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;   
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
#myModal{
   float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inside">
      <div class="container-title">Images</div>
      <br>
      <div class="proof-container">
        <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="https://wallpaperstock.net/wallpapers/thumbs1/45957hd.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
            <span>2nd Feb, 2017 (01:02 pm)</span></div>
        </div>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
          <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="https://wallpaperstock.net/wallpapers/thumbs1/45957hd.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
            <span>2nd Feb, 2017 (01:02 pm)</span></div>
        </div>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
          <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="https://wallpaperstock.net/wallpapers/thumbs1/45957hd.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
            <span>2nd Feb, 2017 (01:02 pm)</span></div>
        </div>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
          <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>
 <div class="image-container"> <img class="myThumb" id="myImg" src="https://wallpaperstock.net/wallpapers/thumbs1/45957hd.jpg" alt="" width="160" height="100">
          <div class="image-text">shreyansh ($8.75)<br>
            <span>2nd Feb, 2017 (01:02 pm)</span></div>
        </div>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal"> <span class="close">&times;</span> <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
          <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```